PHPUnit --order-by duration
So, when trying to order tests by duration, I'm trying to understand how this works.  Or, rather, what's the source of data to determine the duration order?  Is it the serialized code-coverage data phpunit caches?  Is it the logging reports?  Do you need to tell phpunit what to use?
There seems to be very little documentation on the order-by.  Is it ascending or descending?  I want it to be descending b/c we run parallel test suites and want longer tests being executed first - assuming that's not the case.

So, when trying to order tests by duration, I'm trying to understand how this works. Or, rather,

what's the source of data to determine the duration order?

Runtime data, find it in the PHPUnit cache (normally a file in the project worktree named .phpunit.cache.

Is it the serialized code-coverage data phpunit caches?

Not code coverage, just the cache.

Is it the logging reports? Do you need to tell phpunit what to use?

No and no.

There seems to be very little documentation on the order-by.

PHPUnit is open source, you find it fully documented in the sources. And as we're talking about tests and that tests are documentation, you also find tests in the PHPUnit sources.

Is it ascending or descending? I want it to be descending b/c we run parallel test suites and want longer tests being executed first - assuming that's not the case.

See there for your options. And other options. E.g you may want to run failed tests first, and then all other tests in random order.
If the time how long they take is a burden, build out of project and collect the results later.
